# Solving constrained odes's using inbuilt solvers in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, constraints, octave

I would like to solve a set of coupled second  order differential equations using inbuilt Matlab/Octave subroutines. These equations arise when trying to model sliding of mass ($m_2$) over a wedge of  mass ($m_1$) under gravity and neglecting friction on all sliding surfaces. The equations are of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}m_1&0&\sin \theta \\0&m_2&-\sin \theta \\ m_2\tan \theta & -m_2\tan \theta & -\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\ddot{x}_1 \\ \ddot{x}_2\\N\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\-m_2g\end{bmatrix}
$$
subject to initial conditions
$$x_1(0)=\dot{x}_1(0)=0,x_2(0)=\dot{x}_2(0)=0,x_1(0)=\dot{x}_1(0)=0$$
Here $x_1$ and $x_2$ denote the x-displacement of the wedge and the block, respectively and $N$ denotes the (unknown) normal forces between the block and the wedge and $\theta$ denotes the wedge angle.
Rewriting the equations as a set of single order odes's, I get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
0&m_1&0&0&\sin \theta \\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&m_2&-\sin\theta \\
0&m_2\tan \theta &0&-m_2\tan \theta & -\cos\theta 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{y}_1\\\dot{y}_2\\\dot{y}_3\\\dot{y}_4\\N
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
y_2\\0\\y_4\\0\\-m_2g
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I would like to know if one can solve a set of such equations using Matlab/Octave.  Note that I specifically want to retain $N$ and do not wish to eliminate it by manipulating the equations. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. If the term that multiplies $N$ is never zero, then $N$ is an algebraic variable of index 1. Its combination with the ODEs on $x$ yields a system of differentiel-algebraic equations (DAEs). Matlab has some [dedicated solvers](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/solve-differential-algebraic-equations-daes.html#bu75a7z-2), specialised from ODE solvers. The previous link also gives some basics on DAEs.